# ¿Cómo crear archivo en servidor web desde un WebService? C#

Tags: c#, webservice, archivo, pdf, itext

Estoy tratando de crear un PDF con itext7 en un servidor web a través de un WebService, pero cuando verifico si el directorio que voy a usar existe, el método crashea y me dice lo siguiente:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/Pruebas/Gestion/Files_Site' is denied.

Ya hablé con el servicio del hosting y esa carpeta tiene permisos de escritura, incluso volvieron a resetearlos por si acaso.

Este es el código que tengo en el metodo para crear el PDF:

```
using iText.IO.Font.Constants;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas;
using iText.Layout;
using Servicios.Tablas;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

namespace Servicios.Clases
{
    public class CreaPDF
    {
        PdfWriter writer;
        PdfDocument docPDF;
        Document document;
        PdfFont HelveticaBold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.CP1252, false);
        iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment izquierda = iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.LEFT;

        public string WebPDF()
        {
            directory = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath + "/Gestion/Files_Site";
            (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory)){
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            }

            string pdf = directory + "CheckList.pdf";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(pdf)){
                System.IO.File.Delete(pdf); //Si el archivo ya existe, primero lo borro
            }
        
            writer = new PdfWriter(pdf);
            docPDF = new PdfDocument(writer);
            document = new Document(docPDF);

            document.SetFont(HelveticaBold);
            document.ShowTextAligned("Estado", 20, 535, izquierda);
            document.ShowTextAligned("Accion", 80, 535, izquierda);

            document.Close();
            docPDF.Close();
            return "OK";
        }
    }
```

Si saco la verificación del directorio, tengo la misma excepción al verificar si existe el archivo, y si saco también la verificación del archivo, me dice que falta una dll (BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll) en el servidor, la cual no uso para nada en este proyecto. Si copio esta dll, tengo problemas en el sitio ya que usa criptografía de iTextSharp.

Ya se me agotaron las ideas y en Google no encuentro respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para definir una ruta dentro del sitio web se deberia usar el `HttpContext` de este tendras el `Server.MapPath()`

Entonces quedaria

```
directory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Gestion/Files_Site");
```

como ya tienes el

```
using System.Web;
```

no deberias tener problema para utilizarlo

[HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String) Método](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Ya lo probé y me devuelve `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &#39;BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e99375e54769942&#39; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` y como dije antes, si copio esa .dll (que no uso para nada en el proyecto) entra en conflicto con la de itextsharp

Comment: eso puede ser porque es una libreria que requiere itext7, agrega la referencia a esta usando nuget y valida que este en el `\bin` cuando publicas

Comment: La referencia ya existe porque es algo de iText7 y la copié en `\bin` pero entra en conflicto con otra clase que usa itextsharp: `The type 'Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\pruebas\8055bb4b\28292ea\assembly\dl3\c6176de9\0d178230_bc86d601\BouncyCastle.Crypto.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\pruebas\8055bb4b\28292ea\assembly\dl3\f87ea482\ae119f8a_1f5dd501\itextsharp.DLL'`

Comment: Esa clase que entra en conflicto en realidad pertenece a otro proyecto que se aloja en el mismo servidor web (el mío es una App de Xamarin donde tengo un WebService, el otro proyecto es el sitio web donde se modifican los datos que veo en mi App)

Comment: Creo que estamos desvirtuando la pregunta original, el problema era sobre la creacion de una carpeta, o sobre conflictos con librerias? si el problema cambio entonces crea una nueva pregunta para tratarlo

Comment: Era un poco de las 2 cosas... lo que hice por el tema de la librería fue crear otra "aplicación" dentro del dominio del sitio para poner ahí los webservices, pero el problema principal de esta pregunta fue resuelto, por eso queda marcada como tal